# Spring add external spring context at runtime

Tags: java, spring

We have a homepage that contains multiple components (widgets), kinda like a portal containing portlets. Some of these widgets will be delivered ad jars from other teams and some of those will require some custom beans to be managed by Spring. One solution might be to import spring contexts using the import statement with I wildcard (e.g. import all contexts in the classpath matching context-widget-*.xml).

However, I prefer a more programmatic solution where I check for each widget which context they need loaded (from the classpath). I did not find any blog or such that explains this but did find some posts on forums that explain that this would be a parent-child context and this will only be unidirectional; unfortunately in my case it needs to be bidirectional.

So after some browsing in the API I managed to come up with something working but I am not confident it is a good solution or it there are any pitfalls I did not think about. Perhaps there is another (better) solution for this scenario?

```
public class WidgetManager implements ApplicationContextAware
{

    @Autowired
    private WidgetService widgetService;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext parentApplicationContext) throws BeansException {
        //I do need the parent context to have finished initializing beans
        List<WidgetTO> widgets = widgetService.findAllWidgets();

        List<String> contexts = newArrayListWithCapacity(widgets.size());
        for (WidgetTO widget : widgets) {
            if (isNotBlank(widget.getSpringContext())) {
                contexts.add(widget.getSpringContext());
            }
        }

        AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext parentContext = (AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext) parentApplicationContext;

        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(contexts.toArray(new String[] {}), parentApplicationContext);
        String[] singletonNames = context.getBeanFactory().getSingletonNames();
        for (String s : singletonNames) {
            //copy all singletons that don't already exist from child to parent
            if (!parentContext.getBeanFactory().containsSingleton(s)) {
                parentContext.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton(s, context.getBeanFactory().getSingleton(s));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You did not mention why do you need those beans accessible in the parent context. Maybe it does not have to be bidirectional? It may cause conflicts and other unpredictable results.

Comment: Good point, it's actually a wicket application (should have mentioned this). The homepage is a wicket WebPage and the widget a wicket Panel (which is initialized by reflection). When creating the widget panel the bean (defined in the child context xml) will be looked up by Wicket (@SpringBean). I guess wicket will lookup this bean in the parent context (is it aware of any child context)? At least, when I simply create a new ClasspathAppcontext that references the parent context the bean can't be found (unless I define it in the parent context xml).

Comment: I see, unfortunately I'm not familiar with wicket but I would heavily investigate the mechanism behind @SpringBean (SpringComponentInjector?). Maybe you can customize/replace it and implement an extended lookup which scans all children contexts. I would seriously consider such algorithm with explicit lookup order - what if bean names overlap? - over somewhat undeterministic parent context as a global space.

Comment: 2 comments here: 1. the parent context already needs to be refreshed (initialized) before the child contexts are read and added since to know which child contexts to add I need a (parent) bean (widgetService) to be available. 2. I guess I prevent to duplication by `if (!parentContext.getBeanFactory().containsSingleton(s))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually exactly how I did it. We have been using this fashion for over 3 years and never had issues.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use AutowireCapableBeanFactory. This class lets you add beans to your existing Spring context. It will instantiate beans and inject their dependencies.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html

I'm not sure I understand the "bidirectional" context thing you're talking about. Do you need your primary context beans to have dependencies on beans from the "child"/additional contexts? If so, wildcard imports are probably your best bet, even if you don't prefer that solution.

It might be helpful if you explained in a little more detail your overall application lifecycle, describing the stages for your "parent"/primary context and your "child"/additional contexts.